# Cannot figure out improper string splicing

Tags: python, string, indexing

I am making a function which takes a tuple containing strings, selects one string, then selects a start and end index within that string. Within this index, the string is chopped up into pieces and permuted randomly and then the tuple is returned with the modified string. However, there appears to be some sort of error when defining the start and end index in the function and then splicing the string based on it. In some runs it works as expected, and in others it does not and hence throws an error which I avoid in the while loop. Can anyone tell me what could be going on here:

```
def chromothripsist(seqs, keep_frequency = 0.9):
seqs = list(seqs)
c = list(range(len(seqs)))
chrom = random.sample(c, 1)
orig_seq = seqs[chrom[0]]
n = len(orig_seq)
NotLongEnough = True
while(NotLongEnough): 
    splits = random.randint(5,10)
    ##IF SPLITS > len(seq) then this bugs 
    print(orig_seq)
    lowbd = int(0.1*n)
    upbd = int(0.9*n)
    distance = int(np.random.uniform(lowbd, upbd))
    stidx = random.randint(0,n-1)
    edidx = max(stidx + distance, n-1)
    dist = edidx - stidx
    print(splits, stidx, edidx)
    if(dist > splits): 
        NotLongEnough = False
        break
first_part = orig_seq[:stidx]
last_part = orig_seq[edidx:]
seq = orig_seq[stidx:edidx]
# THE ABOVE LINES ARE NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
print(seq)
print(stidx, edidx)
print(len(seq), splits)
breakpoints = np.random.choice(len(seq), splits-1, replace = False)
breakpoints.sort()
subseq = []
curridx = 0
for i in breakpoints: 
    subseq.append(seq[curridx:i])
    curridx = i
subseq.append(seq[breakpoints[-1]:])
rearrange = np.random.permutation(splits)
#n_to_select= int(splits *keep_frequency)
n_to_select = len(rearrange)
rearrange = random.sample(list(rearrange), n_to_select)
build_seq = ''
for i in rearrange: 
    build_seq += subseq[i]
seqs[chrom[0]] = first_part + build_seq + last_part
breakpoints = list(breakpoints)
return tuple(seqs), [stidx, edidx, breakpoints, rearrange, chrom[0]]
```

Comment: Maybe `edidx = max(stidx + distance, n-1)` should use `min` instead of `max`?

Comment: I think that fixed it thanks